# SQL Server to Linq with a distinct and inner joins

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to get this query to work but I just can't. I'm quite new to entity and linq. Thanks

```
select distinct 
    Usuario.idUsuario, 
    Usuario.Nombre, 
    Usuario.DNI 
from
    Usuario 
right join 
    Relaciones on (Usuario.idUsuario = Relaciones.idUsuario) 
inner join 
    Cursos on (Relaciones.idCurso = Cursos.idCurso)
```

This is what I tried so far

```
var query = from Usuario in db.Usuario
            from Relaciones in db.Relaciones
            where Relaciones.Cursos.idCurso == id
            select distinct Usuario;
```

but the distinct in `select usuario` shoots me an error

Comment: And please show us what you have tried in LINQ.

Comment: done, sorry. The discint gives me an error

Comment: ***WHAT*** error does it return?? We cannot read your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **tell us!**

Comment: this line `select distinct Usuario;` is your problem, you need to wrap your query with `( )` and call distinct on the query.

Answer (score 0):

To emulate the `distinct` sql clause using linq you need to use the [distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) method which returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

```
var query = (from Usuario in db.Usuario
            join Relaciones in db.Relaciones on Usuario.idUsuario = Relaciones.idUsuario
            join Cursos in db.Cursos on Relaciones.idCurso = Cursos.idCurso
            where Cursos.idCurso == id
            select Usuario).Distinct();
```